# Regex Odd/Even Amount

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex question that I do not know how to do. 
It has to match all strings consisting any number of a's at the beginning and then either a single 0 if the number of a's was even or a single 1 if the number of a's was odd.

How can you keep track of even/odd?

Sample

- aaa1
- aaaa0

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Paste some sample strings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`^(a(aa)*1|(aa)+0)$`

or

`^(?:a(?:aa)*1|(?:aa)+0)$` if you are using captures.

The first portion: `a(aa)*1` will match any odd number of a's followed by a one, and the second portion: `(aa)+0` will match any even number of a's followed by a zero.

You can't keep track of the number of matches of a component of the pattern in regular expressions. They don't have memory. Fortunately, you can get around that limitation in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you explain ?:, I know that ? means 0 or 1 but what do they mean together?

Comment: (?:pattern) is just the non-capturing equivalent of (pattern) in Java. If you aren't checking groups in the matcher, both of those patterns are equivalent. In this context, it does NOT mean 0 or 1. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 10):

You could use:

```
^(?:aa)*(?:a1|0)$
```