# Best way to get an odd number of repetitions in regex

Tags: regex

To get an even number of repetitions on a pattern I can do something like:

```
((pattern){2})*
```

What would be the best way to get an odd number or repetitions, that is, 1, 3, 5, ...etc. times?

Comment: `pattern((pattern){2})*`

Comment: @ctwheels thanks, that's it. Want to just put it in an answer and I'll accept it? Perhaps it'll be helpful for people trying to get an even/odd repetitions in the future.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex Odd/Even Amount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18040918/regex-odd-even-amount)

Comment: @ctwheels that answers seems a bit bundled together with the specific question and the answer itself is `^(a(aa)*1|(aa)+0)$`, which I think your answer is much more clear and to the point as to how to do this.